# Magento 2: how to add City in dropdown?

Tags: magento2, checkout, address

Is there any way to add cities as drop down?

I want to add a city drop down for a specific country, there will be no states and city drop down to be shown on the registration page, checkout out the page and all other address books like shipping address and billing address.

Comment: Could you be little clear , what exactly you want and where these drop down you need

Comment: I want to add a city drop down for a specific country, there will be no states and city drop down to be showed on registration page, checkout out page and all other address books like shipping address and billing address.

Comment: maybe have sense to create google autocomplete in text input?

Comment: Sorry , but can't do google autocomplete

Comment: Any one tried with city drop down? Using UI component or extending the directory module with adding dependency to the city and country

Answer (score -2):

You need to add regions into `directory_country_region` and  `directory_country_region_name` table. And Magento 2 **`RegionUpdater`** will  do the trick.

Comment: And the award for the highest use of  `region` in one paragraph goes to...

Comment: Sorry, but it does work for state not city